# Redirecting a page in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a option for [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sv5R.png) in my app. I am using AngularJS to write. I would like to see the contents on the Tablet View page but when I try to load it give me an error saying 
[ng:areq] Argument 'TabletViewController' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=TabletViewController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Here is what my [app.configjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULqzD.png) has.

Comment: Your tablet view controller is not defined because you haven't included it as a script in your html.

Comment: check if your controller (TabletViewController) is properly declared and it's file is referenced in your index.html

Comment: Yes, that's right. I added it to my index.html and it works. Thanks guys.